# How to insert value in database table by importing excel file using php

Tags: php, csv

my file upload code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lumino - Dashboard</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Custom Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        .import {
            right: -430px !important;
            padding: 25px!important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .import {
                right: 0px !important;
            }
            .navbar-fixed-bottom,
            .navbar-fixed-top {
                right: 86px!important;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 1030;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <?php include('dbc.php');?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <span>Lumino</span>Admin</a>
              <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                          <em class="fa fa-envelope"></em>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                          <li>
                              <div class="dropdown-messages-box">
                                  <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
                                      <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/40/30a5ff/fff">
                                  </a>
                                  <div class="message-body">
                                      <small class="pull-right">3 mins ago</small>
                                      <a href="#"><strong>John Doe</strong> commented on <strong>your photo</strong>.</a>
                                      <br/>
                                      <small class="text-muted">1:24 pm - 25/03/2015</small>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>
                              <div class="dropdown-messages-box">
                                  <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
                                      <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/40/30a5ff/fff">
                                  </a>
                                  <div class="message-body">
                                      <small class="pull-right">1 hour ago</small>
                                      <a href="#">New message from <strong>Jane Doe</strong>.</a>
                                      <br/>
                                      <small class="text-muted">12:27 pm - 25/03/2015</small>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>
                              <div class="all-button">
                                  <a href="#"><em class="fa fa-inbox"></em> <strong>All Messages</strong></a>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                          <em class="fa fa-bell"></em>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div><em class="fa fa-envelope"></em> 1 New Message
                                      <span class="pull-right text-muted small">3 mins ago</span></div>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div>
                                    <em class="fa fa-heart"></em> 12 New Likes <span class="pull-right ext-muted small">4 mins ago</span>
                                  </div>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#">
                                  <div>
                                    <em class="fa fa-user"></em> 5 New Followers <span class="pull-right text-muted  small">4 mins ago</span>
                                  </div>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div id="sidebar-collapse" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
        <div class="profile-sidebar">
            <div class="profile-userpic">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/30a5ff/fff" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-usertitle">
                <div class="profile-usertitle-name">Username</div>
                <div class="profile-usertitle-status"><span class="indicator label-success"></span>Online</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <form role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><em class="fa fa-dashboard">&nbsp;</em> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="widgets.html"><em class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp; </em> Widgets</a></li>
            <li><a href="charts.html"><em class="fa fa-bar-chart">&nbsp; </em> Charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="elements.html"><em class="fa fa-toggle-off">&nbsp; </em> UI Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="panels.html"><em class="fa fa-clone">&nbsp;</em> Alerts &amp; Panels</a></li>
            <li class="parent ">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1">
                    <em class="fa fa-navicon">&nbsp;</em> Multilevel 
                    <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-1" class="icon pull-right"><em class="fa fa-plus"></em></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-1">
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="#">
                            <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="#">
                            <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="" href="#">
                            <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> Sub Item 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="login.html"><em class="fa fa-power-off">&nbsp;</em> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-->
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 
     main">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <!--/.row-->
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" role="form" class="impfile">
            <h1 class="text-center">IMPORT FILE</h1>
            <p class="search_input col-sm-12  import">
                <input type="file" placeholder="From Date" id="file" name="file" required class="input-control" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="import" value="import" id="import" class="btn btn-primary pull-center">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE) ?>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST["import"])) {
          ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
          //$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
          $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          //$ext=substr($file,strrpos($file,"."),(strlen($file)- 
          strrpos($file,".");
          //if($ext=="csv")
          $handle = fopen($file, "r");
          //$c = 0;
          while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false)
          {
            $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[0]);
            $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[1]);
            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[2]);
            $url =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[3]);
            $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[4]);
            $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$filesop[5]);
            //print_r($filesop[0]);
            var_dump($filesop);
            //echo $filesop[0];
            $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";
            //$c = $c + 1;
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
            //echo $sql;
            //echo $filesop[1];
            //echo "success";
            exit();
          }
          //if($result){
            //echo " upload success";
            //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);
            fclose($handle);
          // }
          //else
          // echo "cannot upload csv file";
        }
      mysqli_close($conn);        
    ?>
    <!--/.main-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
                var chart1 = document.getElementById("line- 
                    chart ").getContext("
                    2 d ");
                    window.myLine = new Chart(chart1).Line(lineChartData, {
                        responsive: true,
                        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
                        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
                        scaleFontColor: "#c5c7cc"
                    });
                };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my csv file data.

Marketing & Customer Analytics,Trends & Product Updates,Segment Launches Segment Select,https://martechseries.com/analytics/customer-data-platforms/segment-launches-segment-select-new-program-help-companies-leverage-first-party-data-certified-partners/,"Segment, the customer data infrastructure company, launched Segment Select, a new program designed to help Channel and Technology Partners easily build and implement solutions for their customers that leverage Segment’s Customer Data Infrastructure (CDI).",2/24/2019

My database table screenshort
[image]

Comment: Instead of the screenshot, can you run the following command and share the output? `SHOW CREATE TABLE report;`

Comment: Also, what is probably causing some confusion is that the first column in your comma separated values (CSV) files, contains commas. Are the commas commented out or is the string wrapped in quotation marks?

Comment: Marketing & Customer Analytics is the value of category column in report table.Trends & Product Updates is the value of tags column in report table.

Comment: Ok, I had a closer look at your code, what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.I  want to insert csv file values in database table when I click on import button.

Comment: Let's start here: Is this true: `isset($_POST["import"])`?

Comment: isset($_POST["import"]) is true

Comment: Next step: if you do a `var_dump($filesop);exit;` in the beginning of your `while()` loop, can you post what you get? Is it what you expected?

Comment: var_dump($filesop);exit;  returns NULL

Comment: So there's your problem, The file is not being read. There is another answer, it may contain the answer to why the file is not being read.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed form attribute `enctype`.

You need to update in form attribute `enctype` in the form tag.

Your current syntax is:- `<form method="post" role="form" class="impfile">`

**Need to update with** :- `<form method="post" role="form" class="impfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

**Please check below code:**

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="impfile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1 class="text-center">IMPORT FILE</h1>
    <p class="search_input col-sm-12  import">
        <input type="file" placeholder="From Date" id="file" name="file" required class="input-control" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="import" value="import" id="import" class="btn btn-primary pull-center">
    </p>
</form>
```

**Updated**

Update for If CSV file contains 2 or more rows. Please check below code

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== false) 
{ 
  if (empty($fields)){
    $fields = $row;
    continue;
  }         
  foreach ($row as $k=>$value) 
  {   
    $results[$col][$k] = $value;
  }
  $col++;
  unset($row);
}
if (!feof($handle)) 
{
  echo "Error: unexpected fgets() failn";
}
fclose($handle);

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[0]);
  $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[1]);
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[2]);
  $url =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[3]);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[4]);
  $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value[5]);
  $sql = "insert into report(category,tags,title,url,description,date) values ('$category','$tags','$title','$url','$description','$date')";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: I have tried . only id(autoincrement)  and date 0000-00-00  values are inserting .other column values  are empty. but I have value in my  csv file.

Comment: This code is working properly I have tested. Is there any error?

Comment: @Revathi : And you can check `print_r($_FILES);` what is output this code?

Comment: It is working .but if my csv file contains 2 or more rows  it is inserting only one row

Comment: @Revathi:- Please check the updated answer. It works for you.